# Can't find Files\OpenLink class when launching Kafka server

Tags: apache-kafka, classnotfound

I can't launch Kafka on Windows 10, whatever parameter that I pass to the kafka-server-start.

Do you know what is happening ?

[Error when launching Kafka](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EznaI.png)

Thank you very much.

**EDIT**

My configuration file server.properties:

> broker.id=0
>
> listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
>
> num.network.threads=3
>
> num.io.threads=8
>
> socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
> socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
> socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
> log.dirs=C:\tmp\kafka-logs
>
> num.partitions=1
>
> num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
>
> offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
> transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
> transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
>
> log.retention.hours=168
>
> log.segment.bytes=1073741824
>
> log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
>
> zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
>
> zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
>
> group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0

Comment: Can you provide more info on how you installed kafka on windows?  Based on the error description, it seems that kafka expects some directories, but only found invalid symbolic link on windows.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I just downloaded the src folder of kafka, unzip it in C:/ and modify server.properties like that: log.dirs=C:\tmp\kafka-logs and listeners=PLAINTEXT:\\localhost:9092

Comment: Even when I tried with listeners commented it doesn't work and with C:/tmp/kafka-logs too.